# Configure VirtualHost for a perfect Wordpress Environment

Tags: wordpress, apache2, virtualhost, httpd.conf, rackspace

I'm trying to install wordpress in a Cloud Server with rackspace.

But my lack of knowledge in server configuration (LAMP , etc) is making me do a lot of miss configurations .

First I think the .httaccess is not allow.
Second the update Wordpress and plugins featured is not allow
Third may be more numbers...

let me show my virtualhost file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin adrian@my.com
  ServerName  my.com
  ServerAlias www.my.com


  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html, index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/devdreams/domains/my.com/public


  # Custom log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/devdreams/domains/my.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/devdreams/domains/my.com/log/access.log combined

    <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
      Satisfy all
    </Directory>

  AccessFileName .htaccess


    <Directory /home/devdreams/domains/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>


    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"

    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so


</VirtualHost>
```

Could somebody help me configure my VH for a wordpress environment

thaaks

Comment: Probably better posted on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok , let me go there also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your .htaccess will not work because you have `AllowOverride None`, change that to `AllowOverride All`

In terms of being able to update Wordpress and the plugins you will need to change the ownership of the files/directories to the user that is running the webserver. For example:  `chown -R apache:apache /home/devdreams/domains/`

Comment: Yeah that do the trick! thanks @MoovTony . 

Now concerning wordpress update and plugin updates, Wordpress always ask me for ftp and pass .. how can I get override of this option a make wp detect this ?

Comment: For updating WP the user that runs the webserver (usually apache) must be the owner (or have write permission) of your website files and directories. If the user is apache, this command will work:    chown -R apache:apache /home/devdreams/domains/

Comment: Regarding updating and upgrading in a secure way using ssh, I found this tutorial very helpful: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu